# AP Calc Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, which of the following must be true? There is a $c \in [a,b]$ with

1. $f(c) = 0$
2. $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$
3. $f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Choices: 2 only, 3 only, 1 and 2 only, 2 and 3 only, and 1,2, 3.

I know that the first one is not true. A function is not required to touch the $x$-axis in a given interval.

The second one is the mean value theorem, and it appears to be correct.

The third one is about the average value of a function, which I'd expect to lie between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, considering the intermediate value theorem. Plus, it's the same this as the Mean Value Theorem but integrated.

The answer is supposed to be 3 only, but why is 2 not correct? Is it because we don't know about differentiability over the interval? In that case, shouldn't 3 be invalid also? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second might not be true since not any continuous function is differentiable! It's well know that if f is continuous on [a,b] then the function $F(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ is differentiable on [a,b], and I think you apply the mean value theorem to that to get part III!

Comment: Does that imply that III is invalid too since, its just the the integrated version of II? @mich95

Comment: I edited the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I is not true because consider $f(x) = x^2+1$. $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

II is not true because consider $f(x) = |x|$ which is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But consider the interval $[-1,1]$. $\displaystyle \frac{|1| - |-1|}{1-(-1)} = 0 \neq f'(c)$ for ANY $c\in\mathbb{R}$. This is because $f'(x) \in \{-1,1\}$.

III is true because of the Average Value Theorem for integrals.

So III only.

Answer (score 1):

The second is invalid since it doesn't specify whether the function is differentiable. However, the mean value theorem for integrals does not require differentiability as far as I am aware.